# RxJS Typescript: Property 'reduce' does not exist on type 'Observable<number>'

Tags: typescript, npm, rxjs

I have this little snippet

```
const observable:Observable<number> = Observable.from([1, 2, 3])
  .reduce((sum: number, number: number) => {
    return sum + number
}, 0)
observable.subscribeOnNext((sum) => console.log(sum))
```

It works as expected, but the Typescript compiler produces this error:

> error TS2339: Property 'reduce' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

If `reduce` is changed to `scan`, the error goes away (= the definition of `scan` is found by the compiler, but the definition of `reduce` not).

I'm using npm, and have typescript (2.0.10), rx (4.1.0) and @types/rx (2.5.34) installed.

Comment: It looks like a recent commit [added `typings`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/package.json), so you might be able to use that - try `npm install --save Reactive-Extensions/RxJS` (and remove the old version of RxJS and the types you have installed).

Comment: Yes, thats working, thanks! Do you want to post that as an actual answer, so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of RxJS 4 on [GitHub](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/package.json) has added a `typings` declaration and the relevant `d.ts` files that define the types for TypeScript.

Simply upgrade to the latest version by removing the old `rx` and `@types/rx` modules and run:

```
npm install --save Reactive-Extensions/RxJS
```

Note the syntax `Reactive-Extensions/RxJS` which is shorthand for using the GitHub repository's source code.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that generates this error is how you import Observable.  I had

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
```

which caused the same error, by changing it to

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx'
```

it resolved the reduce method correctly.  Something else to check.